# Programming to find if a 2D circle is obstacle-free

Tags: math, graphics, 2d, collision-detection, game-physics

In a 2D plane, there is a circle with its center(x,y) and radius r. What is the efficient way to programmatic find if there is any obstacle inside the circle?

Of course, One way to solve the problem is to iterate through each point in the circle to check whether there is an obstacle in that location ([How do you loop through a circle of values in a 2d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590846/how-do-you-loop-through-a-circle-of-values-in-a-2d-array)), but is there any better way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: The way you formulated it would be pretty calculation intensive. You either need an array that contains for every coordinate in the 2D plane all the id's of elements that occupy it *or* you need an array that contains all the elements existing in the plane and check if any of them cross any coordinates circle. Both options are far from ideal in my opinion.

Comment: It would be probably helpful to state how you generate geometric objects in the plane and/or keep track of them

Comment: Hi Pankrates, thanks for your comment, some geometric objects(obstacles) are already there in the plane, and these obstacles may not be static. Now I randomly generate a circle with center(x,y) and radius r in the plane, but I must propose an algorithm to make sure the random generated circle should be collision free.

Comment: Ok that already helps a lot. How do you define your coordinates, are they continuous or (as I expect) have you defined a grid with a specific finite step between points?

Comment: Basically the coordinates are just based on pixels on computer graphics. So each finite step would be 1px.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The circle has a center and a radius. Check if in the plane there is a point (x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>), such that:

(x<sub>0</sub> - x)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>0</sub> - y)<sup>2</sup> ≤ r<sup>2</sup>

Comment: should be square root of x^2+y^2

Comment: The radius should be squared in your formula.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question, please check my update comment and the reply the Pankrates.